# Radeon Driver HD 6470M on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: radeon, hd6470m

Couple weeks ago my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS was unable to start and wanted automatically update to 14.04 LTS.

All other programs and software I was able to fix and update but I cant find the way to set up my Radeon Drivers HD 6470M.

Only Catalyst 14.6 Beta sounds reasonable. I have only this kind of screen on my system setting as this:

[image]

So any tips what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is useful? http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Generate_a_new_.2Fetc.2FX11.2Fxorg.conf_file

That's what I used to install my Radeon HD drivers (Catalyst).